# Java graphics multicore CPU very slow

Tags: java, awt, gpu, cpu, graphics2d

We have java code that uses graphics2d in order to convert some graphics.
When I run it on a 32 cores machine it does not utilize all cpu power, its around 3%.
I read somewhere that this library uses GPU instead of CPU.
Does anybody know how to force it using cpu? 
Or is there a library that uses cpu for this purpose?

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: How could anyone answer a question about your library if you don't tell what library it is? Also, If on a 32 core machine you get 3% used, that implies that your lib runs on a single core. Probably you could easily process 32 tasks in parallel to speed things up. But it all depends on your program.

Comment: We use java.awt.image pkg. 3% is when 32 threads are run. When no graphics operations are executed, then all cores are fully loaded. How to force java to run graphics operations on cpu, not on gpu which in our server is very slow.

Comment: How are you scheduling your different conversion-threads? Is there some Swing involved and the consversion somehow end up having to run on the EDT?

Comment: I schedule threads with executor. Threads are perfectly fine. As I checked, settings that switch off hardware support for java do not work. I am sure that java redirect gfx operations to GPU. When i replaced drawImage method with my own method that pixel by pixel creates a converted image, i got cpu utilization at 100% and overall process performance is 50x better than using gpu based. I know that with one cpu, gpu performs much better, but in my case i have 32 cpu and 1 low end gfx card and this was the bottleneck